# Retrieving the COM Class factory

Tags: .net, com

I am building an application on VSS 2010 ,.Net 4.0 and Widows 7(64 bit).

I am using a 3rd party component for encryption and decryption of passwords.

I referenced to the 3rd paty dll in my application and wrote the code.

When I am trying to run on my integrated VSS web server,it is giving the following error,

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {B72DF070-28A4-11D3-BF19-009027438003} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean
>   fillCache) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean
>   nonPublic) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) at
>   EncryptProject.HashString.hashstring(String password, String pwsalt)

But it is working fine when I move these code dlls to the Production server.

I searched through the Internet and got some suggestions to change the target to platform to x86,x64...

I tried in all the possible ways but no use.

It would be great if some one helps me in solving this problem.

So that I can debug my application in the local system only.

Thanks in advance,

Regards..

Answer (score 4):

1. Is your server an x86 machine?
2. Is this 3rd part COM server compiled as x86 ?

If the answer to these questions is a **yes** then just compile your code as x86 instead of x64 (that's the most likely cause) and it should work.